# How to upgrade svn client from 1.6.16 to 1.7.2 using TortoiseSVN and PushOk

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

For those who dont know PushOk... Its a plugin for the Sybase PowerBuilder IDE (strange thing...).

There is a new PushOk version released. Linked against Subversion 1.7.2.

We like to upgrade the clients using TortoiseSVN.

How do we have to do that? Can we just install the new TortoiseSVN over the old version or do we have to migrate the working copy in some kind of way?

Many thanks for reading and answering this!

Answer (score 1):

See http://tortoisesvn.net/tsvn_1.7_releasenotes.html:

> Subversion 1.7 introduces substantial changes to the working copy format. In previous releases, Subversion would automatically update the working copy to the new format when a write operation was performed. Subversion 1.7, however, will make this a manual step.
>
> Before you can use an existing working copy with TortoiseSVN 1.7, you have to upgrade the format first. If you right-click on an old working copy, TortoiseSVN only shows you one command in the context menu: Upgrade working copy.
>
> To be on the safe side, you should run a cleanup with your pre-1.7 svn client on all your working copies, because if the working copy is in an inconsistent state the upgrade process might fail. Best to run cleanup before installing the new version of TortoiseSVN.
>
> Even after cleanup the upgrade process does not always run as smoothly as it should, and it can be quite slow. We recommend that you commit all changes to your working copy (using your pre-1.7 client) before upgrading. If the upgrade fails for any reason, just make a fresh checkout.

Comment: thanks, JB Nizet. This explains one half of it :-)
The PushOK part is still a miracle and i have heaps of problems... Support is involved...